# Freebsd - include "machine" what is this?

Tags: header, include, freebsd

Can someone explain me where the headers like

`#include <machine/elf.h>`

are located in the freebsd source tree?

I cannot find it anywhere..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'machine' is a symlink created for the target architecture. You can find relevant elf.h files in sys//include/elf.h. You could have easily find out yourself if you built the kernel and inspected the tree.

Comment: Yes but I am not interested into building it right now. Thanks koro